# Trouble Importing in Ipython: ImportError: No module named 'ipdb'

Tags: python, ipython, importerror, ipdb

I've run `pip install ipdb` but when I run `import ipdb` in `iPython` I still get the error: `ImportError: No module named 'ipdb'`

What does this mean?

Similarly, when I'm importing files (with .py extension) in iPython, I'm also getting this error `(ImportError: No module named Chapter_1_Python_Syntax)` though I've checked the path to the directory and it's correct.

Comment: Can we see some code that you've tried? That way we're more capable of diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

When I get this error after using 'pip install', closing and restarting the terminal usually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems getting pip installs to work properly for me. Usually I just end up dropping the file/folder with the rest of the libraries. You can just drop it here: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages and then just import it in your python script and should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

`ipdb` comes with `ipython`, so if you already have `ipython` installed, you can access ipdb through that package using:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb
ipdb = Pdb()
```

Then you could use ipdb just as you though you had done `import ipdb`, like:

```
ipdb.runcall(self, fun, *args, **kwds)
ipdb.run(self, cmd, globals = None, locals = None)
```

If you don't have `ipython` installed, you can just use `pdb` which is the built-in debugger.